# Custom content title not displayed as field

Tags: views, nodes

I have created 2 custom content type "project information" and deleted body and added other fields and using "title" field as "project title ". Now I am creating view, when I am adding FIELDS ,not able to find project title field.

Answer (score 0):

It should be listed under node title. Changing the title in manage fields for a content type only changes the label for the tittle field. Title is a required field for nodes thus you cannot change it's field name.

Comment: I am not able to view node:title. Yes I changed label only.

Comment: Sorry views 3 uses Content: Title now. node:title was views 2.